# how to pass jquery variable one page to another?

Tags: php, jquery

index.php

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
    var field = $("#field").val();
    $("#popular_colleges" ).load( "xyz.php");
    $("#popular_colleges").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("imagen").show();
      var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
      $("#popular_colleges").load("xyz.php",{"page":page}, function(){ 
        $("imagen").hide(); 
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

xyz.php

```
//another page code
```

Here I having two pages i.e. index.php and xyz.php now I want to post  index.php page variable (var field) to xyz.php. How can I do this ? can anyone help me please ?

Thank You

Comment: Uhmmm... this totally depends on your use case? Options are to include the file, make an ajax call via GET or POST, etc. So can you be more precise in what each file's purpose is?

Comment: for sending variable to next page use `ajax`

Comment: Use a Session: $_SESSION['keyname'] = 'value'

Comment: Either use PHP $_SESSION or browser sessionStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post `var field = $("#field").val();` from `index.php` to `xyz.php` you have to use the jquery `ajax()`. To use this you have to include the jquery library in your page and its syntax is like:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'xyz.php',
    method : 'post',
    data : {
        field: field
        // key: value pair
    },
    success: function(response){
        // here response in the response you get from xyz.php
    }
});

xyz.php: you can get the posted value like:

$field = $_POST['field'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.get(), or $.post(), or the more powerful and complex $.ajax().

For a simple value called page, get or post should be sufficient:

```
$.post('/path/to/other-page.php', {page: page}, function(data){
    console.log(data); // what your other page returned
});
```

Comment: is it the page var you want to send? Just put it in the line after `var page = $(this).attr("data-page");`